# How to select near month expiry in mySQL

Tags: mysql

```
Date    Expiry  Close
20-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10143.2
20-Mar-18   26-Apr-18   10180.2
20-Mar-18   31-May-18   10201
21-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10180.2
21-Mar-18   26-Apr-18   10218.3
21-Mar-18   31-May-18   10237.8
22-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10127.8
22-Mar-18   26-Apr-18   10168.8
22-Mar-18   31-May-18   10193.2
23-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10003.9
23-Mar-18   26-Apr-18   10047.6
23-Mar-18   31-May-18   10060.2
26-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10146.2
26-Mar-18   26-Apr-18   10178.3
26-Mar-18   31-May-18   10205
27-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10179
27-Mar-18   26-Apr-18   10215.8
27-Mar-18   31-May-18   10235.2
28-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10120.2
28-Mar-18   26-Apr-18   10152
28-Mar-18   31-May-18   10175.3
2-Apr-18    28-Jun-18   10301.4
2-Apr-18    31-May-18   10288.2
2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10264
3-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10285
3-Apr-18    31-May-18   10313.9
3-Apr-18    28-Jun-18   10327.4
4-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10146.6
4-Apr-18    31-May-18   10175.5
4-Apr-18    28-Jun-18   10194.7
5-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10352.2
5-Apr-18    31-May-18   10381
5-Apr-18    28-Jun-18   10398
6-Apr-18    28-Jun-18   10399.3
6-Apr-18    31-May-18   10385.1
6-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10352.8
```

Each of the Date in the first column has 3 Expiry Dates associated with it. I want to fetch Date, Close, Expiry for only the Expiry which is closest to the Date (Near month expiry).
How can I do it? Thank you.

For example, I want the result as:

```
Date    Expiry  Close
20-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10143.2
21-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10180.2
22-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10127.8
23-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10003.9
26-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10146.2
27-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10179
28-Mar-18   28-Mar-18   10120.2
2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10264
3-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10285
4-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10146.6
5-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10352.2
6-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   10352.8
```

Comment: Can you go into more details? Right now your question is not clear to me.

Comment: I have added what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: What do you mean by closest month ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Posting it here for the benefit of others:

```
SELECT Date, DATE_FORMAT(min(STR_TO_DATE(Expiry, '%d-%b-%Y' )),"%d-%b-%Y") Expiry, Close
FROM table
WHERE Symbol =  'NIFTY'
GROUP BY Date
order by STR_TO_DATE(DATE,  '%d-%b-%Y' )
```

The WHERE clause is additional since my table has a lot of symbols as well.

What it does is, it sorts the Expiry first before grouping with Date and again the result is sorted from oldest to newest Date

Any suggestions to improve is more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, I think in MariaDB this works. Please try this:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Expiry,
    Close
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    Date
ORDER BY
    Expiry DESC
```

Comment: That works only, if the "Expiry" dates are always bigger than the "Date", but it seems to be the case in the OPs example. If not, you can take the (absolute) difference of Date and Expiry and order by that.

Comment: Thanks for it but it breaks sometimes as the Expiry Date is not always sorted. It only gives the first Expiry it finds. I am trying to get the Date with the nearest Expiry value. Eg: If Date = 6-Apr-18 and the Expiry values are 28-Jun-2018, 31-May-2018 and 26-Apr-2018 then it gives Expiry as 28-Jun-2018 instead of 26-Apr-2018

Answer (score 0):

I think luksch ment following, please try  this:

```
 SELECT 
     Date, 
     Expiry, 
     Close,
     DATEDIFF(Expiry, Date) DaysToExpire

 FROM
     table
 GROUP BY 
     Date 
 ORDER BY
     DaysToExpire DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. However, it assumes the Expiries are already sorted which is not the case.

Comment: Actually it doesn't assume Expiry is sorted. That's why DATEDIFF is calculated and used in order by

Comment: Oh yes I see. Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it. However, I have not tested it as of now. Will check.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
SELECT t.`date` , t.`expiry`, t.`close` FROM 
test t INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `date`, MIN(expiry) AS minD FROM test WHERE `expiry`>`date` GROUP BY `date`
) AS minDate
ON t.`date` = minDate.date AND t.`expiry` = minDate.minD;
```

Comment: @Rusty Banks did you get your solution ?